# Retract of Torus without disks

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show that the torus without 2 disks retracts to a boundary of a disk $S^1$. But I'm not really sure how. I drew out the square with opposite edge Identification and removed two disks and I know that deformation retracts to a bouquet of 3 circles but I'm not sure why there is a retract to $S^1$.

I also know that the torus minus a disk does not retract to its boundary $S^1$ but why does it retract when you remove another circle?

Comment: It does retract to something homoropy equivalent  to a bouquet of three circles. Definitely not $S^1$.

Comment: it deformation retracts to a bouquet of 3 circles but I want to show it retracts to $S^1$. They're different.

Comment: Why do you think $S^1 \vee S^1$ has no retraction to $S^1$?

Comment: but how does that help me show there is a retract from the torus without 2 disks to $S^1$

Comment: No, I am asking why did you write that you know there is no retract from punctured torus to the circle? If you can construct a retraction from $S^1 \vee S^1$ to $S^1$ then you can use the same idea to construct a retraction $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$ to $S^1$.

Comment: Look at [this](https://i.imgur.com/rH8ID9D.jpg) picture.

Comment: So a wedge of $n$ circles can retract to a circle?

Comment: I know there is no retract from $T^2 - D^2$ to $S^1$. This is a common problem. You use their homology groups. Although I don't understand homology yet, this was the reasoning I found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116793/discussion-between-feynhat-and-sasha).